# How to set index on categorical type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

Given this Dask DataFrame :

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
             date  value           symbol
npartitions=2                                
           object  int64  category[known]
...              ...
...              ...
Dask Name: from-delayed, 6 tasks2130
```

How can I set_index on 'symbol' column (which is category[known)?

```
df = df.set_index('symbol')
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
TypeError: Categorical is not ordered for operation max
you can use .as_ordered() to change the Categorical to an ordered one
```

Comment: the error msg seems clear : "you can use .as_ordered() to change the Categorical to an ordered one"

Comment: Oh god! Yes you right.. I tested so many things... The good function call is : `df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].cat.as_ordered()`. I missed the `cat`. After that `df = df.set_index('symbol')` works correctly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would you like to give this as an answer, so that others can more easily find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Categorical objects must be defined ordered before they can be indexed. The error message tells us to use the `as_ordered()`. This method comes from the `cat` structure:

```
df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].cat.as_ordered()
df = df.set_index('symbol')
```

Comment: Thanks for adding :)